# Windows 8 phone emulator orientation change button doesn't change or fire "OnOrientationChanged"

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am working on a windows 8 phone project, and I notice that clicking the orientation 
change button in the upper right corner does not run as expected.

The phone emulator changes to being in a landscape position, however the view does not change, and the `OnOrientationChanged` event is not fired.

Also, starting from `PortraitUp`, the PhoneApplicationPage.Orientation property also does not change when doing this. Is this a bug in the emulator, has anyone else had any luck with this?

Is windows 8 phone supposed to automatically re-arrange the UI elements? Even if you don't have a layout designated specifically for that view?

Answer (score 3):

The `OrientationChanged` event is still supposed to work on Windows Phone 8. Make sure you put `PortraitOrLandscape` in the `SupportedOrientations` property of your page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="WP8Application.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"        
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" 
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    OrientationChanged="PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged_1">
```

The point is, if you leave simply `Portrait` or `Landscape` in the supported orientations, the `OrientationChanged` event won't be triggered **because the orientation of your application won't actually change**, even if you rotate your phone.

As for your other question, yes Windows Phone is supposed to automatically re-arrange your UI elements, as you'll discover when correctly setting the `SupportedOrientations` property. In most cases, as long as you're not explicitly setting in pixels the position of your elements, the automatic layout should suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The Orientation should not be Portrait, if you want the Page to work in both types of Orientation, that parameter should be omitted and only leave the SupportedOrientations parameter.
What does not work in the Emulator is the InputScope when you go from Portrait to LandScape.
Nobody seems to mention that.